# how to set the timezone to 'America/New_York' regardless of browser timezone? (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

Is there a way to set the timezone using moment.js or moment-timezone always to reflect 'America/New_York' regardless of where the user is accessing the app from?

I've tried this but the object's timezone is reflective of the browser's timezone and returns America/Los_Angeles.

```
moment.tz("8/26/2013 4:55 pm", "M/D/YYYY h:mm a", "America/New_York")
```

Comment: Your syntax is totally fine here. When I run it, it produces a date with a -4 offset which is correct. When you say 'the object's timezone', what property are you looking at?

Comment: Check the debug console.  Are you getting an error `"Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York"`?  If so, you don't have the tz data loaded.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33263885/634824).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated here,

[Moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

you need to include the timezone module and use it like this:

```
moment("8/26/2013 4:55 pm", "M/D/YYYY h:mm a").tz("America/New_York").format();
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the default time zone, use `moment.tz.setDefault` with a valid time zone:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

[moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/)

Comment: would creating a new moment object afterwards be created under the default timezone? it seems it doesn't if my computer is set to the pacific time zone

Comment: yes, new moment objects will be created with default timezone, which you set in `moment.tz.setDefault(...`.