# World clock not updating with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am new to moment.js and the timezone add-on. Hopefully this isn't a duplicate issue, but I am seeming to have some issues with a world clock using moment.js and moment-timezone.js I am trying to make on a page that also is using highcharts. I am using CodePen and a local IDE and seem to be getting two different errors with the same code. Speaking of which, here is the code in question :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>

<label>Texas
<div id = "USclock" class="circle">
  <div class="face">
    <div id="UShour" class="hour"></div>
    <div id="USminute" class="minute"></div>
    <div id="USsecond" class="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</label>

<label> Staffordshire, United Kingdom
<div id = "Ukclock" class="circle">
  <div class="face">
    <div id="UKhour" class="hour"></div>
    <div id="UKminute" class="minute"></div>
    <div id="UKsecond" class="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</label>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(function() {
function updateClockUS(){
    var now = moment(),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    $('#UShour').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#USminute').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#USsecond').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function timedUpdate () {
    updateClockUS();
    setTimeout(timedUpdate, 1000);
}

timedUpdate();
});

$(function() {
function updateClockUK(){
    var now = moment().tz("Europe/London"),
        second = now.seconds() * 6,
        minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
        hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

    $('#UKhour').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
    $('#UKminute').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
    $('#UKsecond').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
}

function timedUpdate () {
    updateClockUK();
    setTimeout(timedUpdate, 1000);
}

timedUpdate();
});
```

May not be important and I know there are some overlapping issues with it, but here is the css:

```
label {
    top: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    font-size: 30px;
    position:fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    }

 .circle {
     display: block;
   width: 160px;
   height: 160px;
   margin-top: 10px;
     margin-left: -15px;
   position: relative;
   border: 8px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }

 .circle .face {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .circle .face:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 12px;
   height: 12px;
   margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
   background: black;
   border-radius: 6px;
   content: "";
   display: block;
 }

 .circle .face .hour, .circle .face .minute, .circle .face .second {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   background: black;
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
 }

 .circle .face .minute, .circle .face .second {
   transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 }

 .circle .face .hour {
   margin: -4px 0 -4px -25%;
   padding: 4px 0 4px 25%;
   transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 }

 .circle .face .minute {
   margin: -40% -3px 0;
   padding: 40% 3px 0;
 }

 .circle .face .second {
   margin: -40% -1px 0 0;
   padding: 40% 1px 0;
 }
```

On Chrome Developer Tools I am getting a `moment(...).tz is not a function` and on CodePen I am getting `"Moment Timezone has no data for Europe/London. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/."` I used the map on http://momentjs.com/timezone/ to actually use the location so it's not really making sense. On the actual app the UK clock isn't moving at all. Here is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/gabedesigns/pen/GXZPqg?editors=1111

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258908/angular-moment-moment-timezone-has-no-data-for-america-new-york

Comment: @sychd I haven't but I will now. If this fixes my problem I will remove the post. Thank you

Comment: @sychd this fixed my error in codepen, however I am still getting the `moment(...).tz is not a function` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out an older input was causing my issues. I am using some Coldfusion templates and that template had an outdated script imported. Thank you though everyone