# Moment Timezone has no data for IST

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have referred similar questions too, but nothing seems helpful to me. ([Angular Moment : Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258908/angular-moment-moment-timezone-has-no-data-for-america-new-york))

[a simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajKumari_1/cgv06kzu/4/)

```
document.getElementById("output").innerText = moment.tz("IST"); //throws error
document.getElementById("output1").innerText = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata"); 
document.getElementById("output2").innerText = moment.tz.names().includes("IST") // returns false
document.getElementById("output3").innerText = moment.tz.names().includes("Asia/Kolkata")
```

[image]

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.js has data for IST, but why the moment is throwing error when IST is used?
Do i need to manually add IST to timezone? Also, moment.tz.names() doesn't have IST in it, is that the reason for the error?

Comment: You clearly expect IST to have a standard interpretation. It doesn't. There is no canonical list of timezone abbreviations, and in Ireland and Israel IST means something quite different from what you may be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps not particularly helpful to suggest switching packages entirely, but there is a useful alternative to Moment named [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) which has support for IST timezone (I have verified this myself).

As an added bonus, it has a much smaller package size than Moment and comes with pretty much all of the functionality of Moment with an almost-identical syntax as Moment.